# Including momd with tables and attributes inside ios library or framework

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, ios-frameworks

I am trying to convert my ios app with core data into a framework by following the [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial). But how to include momd file inside framework and distribute a framework with momd or core data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be including those frameworks inside your framework. Generally, when you distribute the framework, you will ask the user to include the required frameworks themselves for compatibility reasons (You cannot guarantee the framework you ship will work on everyone elses computers).

For example, if i make a framework that relies on quartz or openGL, i would not share these libraries. I would share my framework and get the user to include those themselves.

As for the momd, i am not sure how you would include that in a framework. Maybe you want to share your app as a bundle instead of a framework. A framework is just for code I think.

Comment: How to develop a bundle with momd in ios world? Bundle option is provided in osx, but not in ios inside xcode